# Syntax Control & Debugging

Tags: c++, debugging, makefile, syntax-checking

How can I make syntax control and debugging on makefile? 
I used g++ compiler.  We can assume that following code our sample makefile.Thanks for your advice.

```
all: sample1
sample1: deneme.o hello.o
         g++ deneme.o hello.o -o sample1
deneme.o: deneme.cpp
         g++ -c deneme.cpp
hello.o : hello.cpp
         g++ -c hello.cpp
```

Comment: Perhaps you're confusing static analysis by 'syntax control'? Syntax is checked by the compiler and your Makefile should suffice for that. For debugging, it's not done in the makefile, you need to add another target with `-g` switch, say `deneme-debug` (and call it with `make deneme-debug`) so you can pass it to `gdb` for debugging if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you have makefile variables such as:

```
DEBUG=-Wall -g
```

and use them in your build commands:

```
sample1: deneme.o hello.o
    g++ deneme.o hello.o -o sample1
sample1-debug: deneme-debug hello-debug
    g++ $(DEBUG) deneme.o hello.o -o sample1
deneme.o: deneme.cpp
    g++ -c deneme.cpp
deneme-debug: deneme.cpp
    g++ $(DEBUG) -c deneme.cpp
hello.o: hello.cpp
    g++ -c hello.cpp
hello-debug: hello.cpp
    g++ $(DEBUG) -c hello.cpp
```

then use `make sample1-degug` for you debug executable.

Answer (score 0):

As for personal experience, I would keep the original structure of the makefile and insert the CDEBUG variable in each g++ recipe line. (of course, the makefile can be improved with [static-patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Pattern.html), which is not the case here). In that way all I have to do to generate a debuggable program is either to change CDEBUG declartion in the Makefile or to [override](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Override-Directive.html) in the make invokation 'make "CDEBUG=-g"'.

```
CDEBUG := -g #(or -ggdb, -g1- -g2 -gdwarf and so on)
all: sample1
sample1: deneme.o hello.o
         g++ deneme.o hello.o -o sample1
deneme.o: deneme.cpp
         g++ $(CDEBUG) -c deneme.cpp
hello.o : hello.cpp
         g++ $(CDEBUG) -c hello.cpp
```

The solution offered by Paul will work, but notice it will create lots of *-debug files which won´t be of any importance. But of course I will be happy to understand otherwise.